# How Can I Access Method to Method Inside the Same Class?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
using namespace std;
class Puzzle
{
public:
    void SetTable() //Is there a better way to do this? (2d array)
    {
        const int four = 4;
        char Table[four][four]=

        {
            {'f', 'k', 's','a'},
            {'l', 'u', 'o','w'},
            {'y', 'o', 'n', 'a'},
            {'x', 't', 'o', 'y'}
        };
    }

    void OutputTable()
    {
        int n=0;
        while (n < 4)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                cout << Table[x][n] << "   "; //error here
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            n++;
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
   Puzzle connect;
   connect.SetTable();
   connect.OutputTable();
   return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to set a 2d array inside the class Puzzle? 
How can I access void SetTable inside void OutputTable?
All variables must be inside the class Puzzle.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about member variables in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Any specific error messages you missed to tell us? I'd recommend using `std::array<std::array<char,four>four> Table;` though.

Comment: @TheDude Why not just use a 1D array and compute indices? Saves memory overhead.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Are you sure that `std::array` implies _memory overhead_? Isn't it guaranteed to be completely contiguous memory allocated, regardless of nested dimensions?

Comment: No, you are correct, my mistake, I thought for some reason we were referring to std::vector. Disregard my comment. Sorry!

Comment: _@Alex_ The `Table` you declare in your `SetTable()` function is only visible inside that function. I'd recommend you declare a class member variable of type `std::array<std::array<char,four>four> Table;`, and initialize it in your constructors member initializer list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will advise you to practice more as this you are showing in your question is wrong and there are many ways to implement it and this is the wrong way because the 2D array as you said is not accessible from anywhere else, making it something like hidden and the function does not sets the contents of the 2D array just declares that there is a 2D array inside the function only.

To help you start, do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Puzzle
{
public:
    char Table[4][4] =
    {
        {'f', 'k', 's','a'},
        {'l', 'u', 'o','w'},
        {'y', 'o', 'n', 'a'},
        {'x', 't', 'o', 'y'}
    };
    // This function will be more useful if the `Table` is not public
    void SetTable(int row, int col, char value)
    {
        Table[row][col] = value;
    }

    void OutputTable()
    {
        int n=0;
        while (n < 4)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                cout << Table[x][n] << "   "; //error here
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            n++;
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
   Puzzle connect;
   connect.SetTable(2, 3, 'A');
   connect.OutputTable();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not compile. =(

Comment: Forgot to change the `connect.SetTable();`. I 've changed it, so you can try again.

Comment: Got this error:                                                                                       
warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is
      a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    char Table[4][4] =
                     ^
1 warning generated.

Comment: Try to add this option `-std=c++11` to your compiler, but it should compile anyways because it is a warning ... not error

Comment: how can I add this? -std=c++11

Comment: Where are you trying to compile this code? Linux, Windows or on something else?

Comment: through Terminal. mac.

Comment: Type `g++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o main` if you are using directly the compiler, else show me what are you typing in your terminal

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Could you tell me why I have to include -std=c++11 in order to compile?

Comment: If your compiler treats some warnings like errors this is the first reason. The second reason is this you are trying to initialize the contents of the `Table` which is not declared static like `static constexpr char Table` which will make the contents read-only and because you want to alter the contents of the `Table` this way is an extension with the C++ 2011 standards

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as a class member variable to realize that.

Your code should look as follows:

```
using namespace std;
class Puzzle
{
    constexpr int four = 4;
    std::array<std::array<char>,four>four> Table;

public:
    Puzzle() : Table {
            {'f', 'k', 's','a'},
            {'l', 'u', 'o','w'},
            {'y', 'o', 'n', 'a'},
            {'x', 't', 'o', 'y'}
        } {}
    }
    // void SetTable() omit that completely

    void OutputTable()
    {
        for(const auto& row : Table) {
            for(const auto& col : row) {
            {
                cout << col << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }    
    }
};

int main()
{
   Puzzle connect;
   connect.OutputTable();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using two identifiers:  `MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLUMNS` instead a constant named "four".  BTW, if the dimensions change, the variable will need to be renamed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Matter of taste. I just left that to be compliant with the OP. Personally I'd prefer simply `4`.